# Why is Raspberry Pi StackExchange still in Beta?

Tags: discussion

I have not experienced any bugs on this site since I started using it, or anything that needs to be added in comparison to the other StackExchange sites.

Sorry, just curious.

Comment: This sounds like a case for the tag [tag:status-completed]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Beta status is not a matter of features, like software, rather it is a measure of developing a healthy and sustainable community.

To measure this stackexchange has some statistical factors that they use to decide when to promote a site out of beta status. These factors are designed to ensure that they promote only healthy and sustainable sites. Some of the statistical factors are the number of answers per question, percent of questions with answers, visits per day etc. You can see these listed in the right column of this [page](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/), and in more detail [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37041/raspberry-pi).

As you can see we are doing very well in some categories, and only OK in others. We have seen progress in the numbers over the last several months which is encouraging, and there is no limit to the amount of time a site can remain in the beta stage.

Comment: Just a harmless addition: GMail stood on beta even after they had most of its core functionalities working. It's really not a matter of features, per say. Our friend here already said everything :)